# select distinct count(id) vs select count(distinct id)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get distinct values from a table. When I ran `select distinct count(id) from table` I got over a million counts. However if I ran `select count(distinct id) from table` I've got only around 300k counts. What was the difference of the two queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you do `select distinct count(id)` then you are basically doing:

```
select distinct cnt
from (select count(id) as cnt from t) t;
```

Because the inner query only returns one row, the `distinct` is not doing anything.  The query counts the *number of rows* in the table (well, more accurately, the number of rows where `id` is not `null`).

On the other hand, when you do:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t;
```

Then the query counts the number of different values that `id` takes on in the table.  This would appear to be what you want.

Comment: I understood why this was happening! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If id is the pk the count with `distinct count(id)` will match the no of rows returned with `count(distinct id)`.

If id is not the pk but has a unique constraint(on id alone, not in combination with any other column), the no of rows returned with `count(distinct id)` will be equal to the count with `distinct count(id)`, as in the case of pk.

If id is just another column, `select count distinct count(id) from table` will return `one row` with the no of records where the id column is NOT NULL where as  `select count count(distinct  id) from table` will return 'one column' with all non NULL unique ids in the table.

In no case will the count or the no of rows returned exceed the total no  of rows in your table.

Answer (score -1):

The second select is definitely what you want, because it will aggregate the id's (if you have 10 records with id=5 then they will all be counted as one record) and the select will return "how many distinct id's were in the table".
However the first select will do something odd, and i'm not entirely sure what it will do.