# SQL Summary How to?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have data like this:

```
Loc Gender ID
1   M       1
1   M       1
1   M       1
1   M       2
1   M       2
2   F       3
2   F       3
2   F       3
```

I want to write SQL to produce the following:

```
M   2
F   1
```

I tried to get this using 1 SQL statement but could not using a mix of Group by and distinct.

I can do a trick of dividing by the count withing each unique LOC and round but it would look ugly.

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

After getting the answer, I found this question which shows a good related point:

[Distinct Count vs. Count Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589606/select-distinct-countid-vs-select-countdistinct-id).

Answer (score 3):

You can use count for counting the distinct ID and group by group the result by gender

```
select gender, count(Distinct ID)
from your_table 
group by gender
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like this generates the total rows on mySQL. I had not tried it for PostgreSQL yet.

Comment: I tried this and it worked select gender, count(Distinct ID) from...Group by gender. Thanks.

Comment: @scaisEdge - Ditinct ??